# How to display the url of navigated page in web browser VB.NET WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am making a web browser in VB.Net in WPF. I want to show the URL of current page in a text block. I am unable to do so. There is no URL property in WPF as it is in WinForms. There is UID property but I don't understand what it is for. There is a SOURCE property again I couldn't get what it does.
As I navigate ahead the URL of that page should be displayed.

For example, I am on google so address bar(which is the text block) should show the URL of GOOGLE when I navigate to YOUTUBE from GOOGLE, so URL should change as per my navigation.

Help PLease. I have less time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `SourceUpdated` and `Navigated` events and set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to the `AbsoluteUri` of the `Uri`:

```
private void wb_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    textBlock.Text = wb.Source.AbsoluteUri;
}

private void wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    textBlock.Text = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: Sir can you tell me code in vb.....? I think the code you gave me is of c#..........WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser; .....didn't work on vb

Comment: i deleted .... WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser.....from both...and code worked thanks.....but tell me what this line is for what i have deleted, what will happen if i don't use it

Comment: You don't need that line if you give your WebBrowser control an x:Name in the XAML. It justs casts the sender argument from object to WebBrowser.

Comment: ok I have given my web browser name in XAML. Thanks for help.

Comment: have an issue whenever I am searching on google everytime I am getting a message "Please click here if you are not redirected within a few seconds." Why am I getting this? any help?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments section.